# On which variables does function depend?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my ODE book (it's not written in English, so I guess there is no point in referencing it) it is said that differential equation of the form $y' = f(at+by+c)$ ($y$ is a function of $t$, and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are some real numbers) can be solved using the substitution $u = at+by+c$ and that $u$ is a function of $t$ only. My question is, shouldn't $u$ be a funtion of $y$ also?

Comment: I guess $y$ is a function of $t$ and hence the whole expression if a function of $t$ ?

Comment: Write the substitution as $u(t) = at + by(t) + c$ instead.

Comment: But still, doesn't function $u$ also depend on a function $y$ that we choose?